# DHTML row values not being captured in SQL Insert

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have some Javascript that dynamically adds rows/fields when you click the button, "Add New Item."  The value for each row is captured in a hidden text field, "txtIndex."  (The initial value of txtIndex is set to 1.)  I then capture txtIndex in a variable in vbscript to loop through the values so that they can be all inserted into a SQL table (the insert is done in the stored procedure, "spInsert").  This is the part that I'm having trouble with.

The first row on the page gets inserted into the SQL table just fine, but when I click the button and add any subsequent rows, those values are not getting inserted into the table; instead, a blank row gets inserted.  So, it's not a SQL issue.  From what I can see when I view the page source, the page is not recognizing that I've added any new rows/values at all.  So, I'm guessing something in my Javascript is off?  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can correct it?  Thanks!

```
<!--#includes file="header.asp"-->

<head>
<title>Offset Input</title>
</head>

<%Dim CN, RS, vIndex, vSQL

'GetDataConnection is included in header file.
Set CN = GetDataConnection

If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
    vIndex = Request.Form("txtIndex")

    If Request.Form("cboOffsetGroupOperator") = "" Then
        Response.Write("Unable to process your request. Please complete a new entry.")
        Response.Redirect("input.asp")  
    Else                
        'Loop through values in txtIndex.  Insert data into table.
        Do While vIndex > 0 
            vSQL = "spInsert "
            vSQL = vSQL & "@vExceptionID = " & RS("ExceptionID") & ","
            vSQL = vSQL & "@vOffsetDetailCorrectionOperator = '" & Request.Form("cboOffsetGroupOperator" & vIndex) & "',"
            vSQL = vSQL & "@vOffsetDetailNumberOfItems  = '" & Request.Form("txtNumberOfItems" & vIndex) & "',"
            vSQL = vSQL & "@vOffsetDetailComments  = '" & Request.Form("txtComments" & vIndex) & "'"

            CN.Execute (vSQL)       
            vIndex = vIndex-1       
        Loop    
    End If
Else%>

<body>
<form name="frmInput" id="Input" method="post">
<table class="WebApps" id="tblOffsetDetail">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <h3>Offset Item Detail</h3> 
            <p><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">    
        <input type="button" class="button" value= "Add New Item" id="btnNewItem" name="btnNewItem" onClick="javascript:addNewItem();">
        <input type="hidden" id="txtIndex" name="txtIndex" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="9%"><h4>Operator:</h4></td>
        <td width="6%"><h4># of Items:</h4></td>
        <td width="13%"><h4>Comments:</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><select name="cboOffsetGroupOperator1" id="cboOffsetGroupOperator1">
                <option></option>
                <option value="1">Name1</option>
                <option value="2">Name2</option>
                <option value="3">Name3</option>
                <option value="4">Name4</option>
            </select></p>
        </td>
        <td><p><input name="txtNumberofItems1" type="text" id="txtNumberofItems1" size="10" maxlength="10"></p></td>
        <td><p><textarea name="txtComments1" cols="20" rows="3" id="txtComments1"></textarea></p></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

<% 
End If

Set RS = Nothing
CN.Close
Set CN = Nothing
%>

<script language="javascript">

//Display additional rows, columns, and fields when Add New Item button is clicked.
function addNewItem()
{
    var iX = document.getElementById("txtIndex").value;
    iX ++;
    document.getElementById("txtIndex").value = iX;

    var tbl = document.getElementById("tblOffsetDetail").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    var tr = document.createElement("TR");
    tbl.appendChild(tr);

    //cboOffsetGroupOperator1
    var tdOffsetGroupOperator = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(tdOffsetGroupOperator);

    var p = document.createElement("P");
    tdOffsetGroupOperator.appendChild(p);

    var cboOffsetGroupOperator = document.createElement("select"); 
    p.appendChild(cboOffsetGroupOperator);

    cboOffsetGroupOperator.id = "cboOffsetGroupOperator" + iX;

    var cboOffsetGroupOperator1 = document.getElementById("cboOffsetGroupOperator1");
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < cboOffsetGroupOperator1.children.length; i++)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value = cboOffsetGroupOperator1 [i].value;
            opt.innerText = cboOffsetGroupOperator1 [i].innerText;
            cboOffsetGroupOperator.appendChild(opt);
        }   

    //txtNumberofItems1
    var tdNumberofItems = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(tdNumberofItems);

    var p = document.createElement("P");
    tdNumberofItems.appendChild(p);

    var txtNumberofItems = document.createElement("input"); 
    p.appendChild(txtNumberofItems);

    txtNumberofItems.id = "txtNumberofItems" + iX;
    txtNumberofItems.setAttribute('size',10);

    var txtNumberofItems1 = document.getElementById("txtNumberofItems1");

    //txtComments1
    var tdComments = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(tdComments);

    var p = document.createElement("P");
    tdComments.appendChild(p);

    var txtComments = document.createElement("textarea"); 
    p.appendChild(txtComments);

    txtComments.id = "txtComments" + iX;
    txtComments.setAttribute('cols',20);
    txtComments.setAttribute('rows',3);

    var txtComments1 = document.getElementById("txtComments1"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form elements you're adding to the DOM don't have names. You need to assign names to them before those names can be used in a form submission.

```
var cboOffsetGroupOperator = document.createElement("select"); 
cboOffsetGroupOperator.setAttribute('name', 'cboOffsetGroupOperator1'); // this is what you're missing
p.appendChild(cboOffsetGroupOperator);
```

And please, as SQLMenace said, fix the SQL injection problem you have in there... to get started, put the following text into the detail comments field and submit it.

> abc ';create table bork(a
>   varchar(30));insert bork values ('all
>   your base are belong to us'); --

However, I encourage you to pay attention to the answer that says your javascript will not work cross-browser. It looks like you need to dig into things a bit to get your code really right.

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm really new to all of this; which form elements don't have names?

I am reading about SQL injection, but I'm not sure I understand your suggestion on that.

Comment: Re my suggestion about SQL injection: See the entire text in the gray-background box above, the one that begins with abc? Copy that whole thing and put it into the last field on your input page. Submit the form, then go look in your database at the new table "bork" that was created.

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions.  I see what you mean now, and definitely will be paying more attention to SQL security going foward.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of JavaScript code is OK for learning how basic DOM and database driven web applications work, but if you intend to have people use this app you must clean up all that JavaScript code since it's not going to work on all browsers. Do yourself a favor and pick up a simple yet powerful library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Also look into an [MVC framework](http://bit.ly/5svTlj) and separate your DB code from the view, and validate your input on both ends.

Ditto on the SQL injection issue.

Good luck.